# Rails mass email is slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, email, cron

We actually have in our back office, a newsletter system who allow use to send a notification to our users. The problem is that we actually have 10,000 users registered and we are sending an email to each users inside a loop which make the process really slow.

```
def send
    users.each do |u|
        @display_name = u.display_name
        mail ( to: u.email, subject: "The day subject" )
    end
end
```

I was going to send it as BCC to make it (maybe) faster but since we need to display the user name in the email template (:display_name), it's unfortunately not possible.

I was thinking maybe delegate it to a cronjob which will send each, let's say 5 minutes, an email to 1,000 poeple at the time (1,000 by 1,000 till reach the amount of total users). The problem is I don't know how and where to start.

Any idea on how make it faster or implement the cronjob system?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using a delayed job gem such as: [delayed jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Also you should probably do something along the lines of

```
users.in_groups_of( 1000, false ).each do |user|
  # mail code here
  @display_name = user.display_name
  mail ( to: user.email, subject: "The day subject" )
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm using Rails 4 and the delayed job does not seems to support that version. I tried also Sidekiq, but I've got an error (undefined method) related to an attribute I want to write in a view so, I feel Im stuck...thoughts?

Comment: use the beta of delayed_job for rails 4 - put this in your Gemfile - `gem "delayed_job", "~> 4.0.0.beta2"` https://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job/versions/4.0.0.beta2

Comment: Could someone explain how sending emails in groups of 1000 is faster? Just don't get that at all...